# How do I delimit my input by this capture group?

Tags: python, regex

For this regular expression:

```
(?<!Mr|Dr|Ms|Jr|Sr)[.?!]+(\s)[A-Z0-9]
```

I want the input string to be split by the captured matching `\s` character - the green matches [as seen over here](https://regex101.com/r/vA8iL6/1).

However, when I run this:

```
import re

p = re.compile(ur'(?<!Mr|Dr|Ms|Jr|Sr)[.?!]+(\s)[A-Z0-9]')

test_str = u"Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars i.e. he paid a lot for it. Did he mind? Adam Jones Jr. thinks he didn't. In any case, this isn't true... Well, with a probability of .9 it isn't.23 is the ish. My name is! Why wouldn't you... this is.\nAndrew"

re.split(p, test_str)
```

It seems to split the string at the regions given by `[.?!]+` and `[A-Z0-9]` (thus incorrectly omitting them) and leaves `\s` in the results.

To clarify:

**Input**: `he paid a lot for it. Did he mind`

**Received Output**: `['he paid a lot for it','\s','id he mind']`

**Expected Output**: `['he paid a lot for it.','Did he mind']`

Comment: You need to remove capturing group. Use [`'(?<!Mr|Dr|Ms|Jr|Sr)[.?!]+\s(?=[A-Z0-9])'`](https://regex101.com/r/vA8iL6/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the capturing group from around `(\s)` and put the last character class into a look-ahead to exclude it from the match:

```
p = re.compile(ur'(?<!Mr|Dr|Ms|Jr|Sr)[.?!]+\s(?=[A-Z0-9])')
#                                          ^^^^^        ^
test_str = u"Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars i.e. he paid a lot for it. Did he mind? Adam Jones Jr. thinks he didn't. In any case, this isn't true... Well, with a probability of .9 it isn't.23 is the ish. My name is! Why wouldn't you... this is.\nAndrew"
print(p.split(test_str))
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/p7xn8N) and [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vA8iL6/3).

Any capturing group in a regex pattern will create an additional element in the resulting array during `re.split`.

To force the punctuation to appear inside the "sentences", you can use this matching regex with `re.findall`:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\s*((?:(?:Mr|Dr|Ms|Jr|Sr)\.|\.(?!\s+[A-Z0-9])|[^.!?])*[.?!]|[^.!?]+)')
test_str = "Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars i.e. he paid a lot for it. Did he mind? Adam Jones Jr. thinks he didn't. In any case, this isn't true... Well, with a probability of .9 it isn't.23 is the ish. My name is! Why wouldn't you... this is.\nAndrew"
print(p.findall(test_str))
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/BQjgHG)

Results:

`['Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars i.e. he paid a lot for it.', 'Did he mind?', "Adam Jones Jr. thinks he didn't.", "In any case, this isn't true...", "Well, with a probability of .9 it isn't.23 is the ish.", 'My name is!', "Why wouldn't you... this is.", 'Andrew']`

[The regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oY0hX1/1)

The regex follows the rules in your original pattern:

- `\s*` - matches 0 or more whitespace to omit from the result
- `(?:(?:Mr|Dr|Ms|Jr|Sr)\.|\.(?!\s+[A-Z0-9])|[^.!?])*[.?!]|[^.!?]+)` - 2 aternatives that are captured and returned by `re.findall`:

  - `(?:(?:Mr|Dr|Ms|Jr|Sr)\.|\.(?!\s+[A-Z0-9])|[^.!?])*` - 0 or more sequences of...

    - `(?:Mr|Dr|Ms|Jr|Sr)\.` - abbreviated titles
    - `\.(?!\s+[A-Z0-9])` - matches a dot not followed by 1 or more whitespace and then uppercase letters or digits
    - `[^.!?]` - any character but a `.`, `!`, and `?`
- or...

  - `[^.!?]+` - any one or more characters but a `.`, `!`, and `?`

Comment: How would you modify to not exclude the `[.?!]+` in the result like in the example I've shown?

Comment: This is possible to some extent, but I'd rather you use `re.findall` then. Let me prep a demo.

Comment: Sounds good - I'm guessing the limitation comes from the fixed-width lookbehind args?